# The line spacing for the subtitle for the CoC on Aviation.SE looks strange

Tags: bug, design, code-of-conduct

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/conduct

I see

[image]

while on other sites I see it normally

[image]

Comment: Looking at it again, looks like the title is low, but not the text after the subtitle, that then is squeezed.

Comment: Same is happening at [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct) - is this being looked at by anyone?

Comment: Seems to have been fixed sometime since then